# GetFunctionPointerForDelegate callback only works once

Tags: c++, c++-cli, interop, .net-5

I'm having trouble with unmanaged-to-managed callback in C++/CLI.   It works exactly one time and then silently fails

My managed `Device` class holds an unmanaged object (`GsDevice`) from a separate DLL.  It gives the unamanaged object a callback function set up via interop.  `GsDevice` needs to asynchronously notify Device when things change.

The callback was silently failing every time.  The debugger was stepping right over it (even in dissasembly.  Then I tried to make `GsDevice` invoke the callback it as the moment it received it.  THEN it works.  Just the one time.

I assume  something is being moved or garbage-collected out from under me but I cannot determine what or why.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Below is the *unmanaged* `GsDevice` class.  It lives in a separate, unmanaged DLL.  I've left out most of it except for the subscription mechanism that the managed client uses and the notify mechanism by which the this class calls back to the managed one.

The .H file

```
struct GsDeviceMembers;
class GsDevice : public std::enable_shared_from_this<GsDevice>
{
    GsDeviceMembers* m_p;   // PIMPL idiom

public:
    typedef void (__stdcall *PROPCHANGECALLBACK)(GsDevice*, const std::string&);
    void GsDeviceDllExport setPropertyChangedCallback(PROPCHANGECALLBACK cb);
protected:
    void raisePropertyChanged(const std::string& prop);
}
```

And the .CPP file

```
void GsDevice::setPropertyChangedCallback(PROPCHANGECALLBACK cb)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk (m_d->mtxClients);
    cb(this, std::string("joe"));   // TEST:  Call callback right away to ensure it's good.
    m_p->cb = cb;                   // Save off the one client's callback
}

void GsDevice::raisePropertyChanged(const std::string& prop)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk (m_d->mtxClients);
    m_p->cb(this, prop);  // Invoke callback:  THIS NEVER WORKS*****
}
```

Below is the managed client `Device` class that tries to receive callbacks from the unmanaged `GsDevice`.

The .H file

```
struct DeviceUnmanagedMembers;  for PIMPL idiom storing unmanaged members.

public ref class Device : public INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public:
    virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged; 

private:
    DeviceUnmanagedMembers* m_p;    // PIMPL idiom
    GCHandle m_callbackHandle;      // Keeps callback locked into one memory address

protected:
    Device(std::shared_ptr<GsDevice> dev);
    delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate(GsDevice* sender, const std::string& propName);
    virtual  void OnPropertyChanged(Gs:Device* pSender, const std::string& propName);

private:
    // I am saving off these as member variables in case it helps .NET keep things
    // alive.  So far, that's not working.

    PropertyChangedDelegate^ m_dg;   
    System::IntPtr^          m_ptr;
};
```

The .CPP file

```
struct DeviceUnmanagedMembers
{
    std::shared_ptr<GsDevice>            spDevice;  
    DeviceUnmanagedMembers(std::shared_ptr<GsDevice> dev) : spDevice(dev) { }
};

Device::Device(std::shared_ptr<GsDevice> dev) : m_p(new DeviceUnmanagedMembers(dev))
{  
    // Get a delegate for our callback function and lock it into memory

    auto pcDelegate  = gcnew PropertyChangedDelegate(this, &Device::OnPropertyChanged);
    m_callbackHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(pcDelegate);
    auto callback    = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pcDelegate);
    auto ptrInt      = callback.ToPointer();
    auto ptrFun      = static_cast<GsDevice::PROPCHANGECALLBACK>(ptrInt); 

    // Now hook up to the unamanged client for a callback.  This actually immediately
    // calls me back (to OnPropertyChanged) but all subsequent attempts by the
    // unmanaged object to call me back do nothing.

    dev->setPropertyChangedCallback(ptrFun);

    // Save off these items just in case it helps (It doesn't)

    m_dg             = pcDelegate;
    m_ptr            = callback;
}

void Device::OnPropertyChanged(GsDevice* sender, const std::string& propName)
{    
    // This is the function the unmanaged client is trying to call back.  It works
    // the very first time the client does it but never after.

    RaisePropertyChanged(propName);  
}
```

Notes:

- Neither `Device` nor `GsDevice` object is being cleaned up.  They both still exist because I continue to invoke them with function calls from managed to unmanaged code.
- The unmanaged device keeps trying and failing to call the callback.  No error.  No exception.  It just steps over the call.
- I've compared the exact pointer values of the callback from the first time (when it works) and all subsequent times when it fails.  Its exactly the same.
- The C++/CLI assembly is built with .NET 5.0 and Visual Studio 2019
- The unmanaged C++ code is built with C++17 features enabled (if that matters)

Comment: You appear to be doing the right things to prevent the garbage collector from tossing out the unmanaged trampoline generated by `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.  (In Fact, either one of `GCHandle.Alloc` or keeping a member variable pointing to the delegate instance should be sufficient, you gain no benefit from doing both)

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I figured.  In fact I'm using this same technique elsewhere with no problems.  This is driving me batty.  If I could at least step into some dissasembly to see where it goes, that would be useful but the disassembler literally steps right over the `call` instruction

Comment: Oh I just noticed that you're accessing a `std::string` across a DLL boundary. That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Question:  Why would accessing a std::string across a DLL boundary ever be a problem?  I do that all the time.  Frankly it's the foundation of the SDK I'm working on.  its entire API is C++ based.   Both of these DLLs are mine, built with the same compiler and based on the DLL version of the same CRT.  Granted one of them is C++/CLI but it's getting CRT memory from the same place that all the others are.

Comment: So long as they are tightly coupled and have to use the same compiler version, same allocator, and so forth, why distribute two DLLs?  The linker will be more than happy to put the native C++ obj files and C++/CLI obj files together into a single DLL.

Comment: The C++/CLI DLL is a managed wrapper on the unmanaged DLL, so that managed clients can use that GsDevice class.  GsDevice still needs to live in the unmanaged DLL  because it still needs to be used by unmanaged C++ clients (specifically a Qt-based application)

Comment: Still not sure why you are making the managed DLL dependent on a separate unmanaged one.  Yes, you'll want to build an unmanaged DLL for use by native clients (but they will suffer from being permanently locked to the same compiler version and settings, so that isn't as useful as you think).  But for managed clients you should provide a single DLL that contains the managed and unmanaged code within itself.  This is known as a "mixed-mode assembly" and creating it should be as simple as toggling the "Link Library Inputs" on the reference from the managed DLL to the unmanaged DLL project.

Comment: Trying to make the managed DLL use the unmanaged DLL suggests that you have dreams of shipping a new version of the unmanaged DLL and having that update apply to all clients, managed and unmanaged.  But you can't do that when sharing `std::string` across the DLL boundary... all consumers of the DLL must be rebuilt and redeployed together with it.

Comment: That is incorrect Ben.  It has been incorrect since Visual Studio 2015.  I know this by experience since before VS 2015 I was forced to maintain different shipping versions of the DLL for VS2012, VS2013, etc.  But once 2015 came around all CRTs then and since have been using the exact same heap, which is no longer with the CRT itself but rather the Windows heap

Comment: I should add that it's also moot because I only ship this DLL with all of its clients rebuilt and included

Comment: It's not enough to use the same heap, you need the same in-memory layout of `std::string`.  Which is guaranteed not to be the same pre-C++11 and post-C++11, but is not guaranteed to be the same when any compiler settings or macros are changed.

Comment: That's not what Microsoft says.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing the right things to prevent the garbage collector from tossing out the unmanaged trampoline generated by `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. (In Fact, either one of `GCHandle.Alloc` or keeping a member variable pointing to the delegate instance should be sufficient, you gain no benefit from doing both).  This is a common trap for use of `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` but it is not your problem.

The other thing I noticed is that you haven't made your delegate suitable for use with `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.  Really, .NET just ought to throw an exception if you use `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` on a delegate type that doesn't have the [**`UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute?view=net-5.0) applied to it.

Add that attribute to `delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate(GsDevice* sender, const std::string& propName);`, set the correct calling convention (and maybe other things), and try again.

Beyond that, your function type really is not .NET-friendly at all.  `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` does not expect to work with types like `const std::string&`.

Does the unmanaged API not provide some user context pointer where you can store a GCHandle to your managed object?  If it does, then make an ordinary non-member function to pass as the callback (which you can now create with just `&name_of_function` -- no delegate, no GetFunctionPointerForDelegate) and in that function, retrieve the pointer, [re-hydrate the GCHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.fromintptr?view=net-5.0), find your managed object, convert the other argument to a `System::String^` and call the .NET member function.

Comment: I actually did try adding the `UnamangedFunctionPointerAttribute` to my delegate.  I specified the `CallingConvention.Stdcal`l argument.  Didn't help.  Then I tried switching it (and the callback signature to __cdecl.  Still didn't help.  I only omitted it here because it seemed superfluous since I get away with not doing it in the other place I use it (where it works.

Comment: I should add that my managed callback function does take std::string and a raw pointer but the raw pointer is only for checking context and the code converts the std::string into a managed System::String before notifying other managed clients via INotifyPropertyChanged.  Frankly I'd be happy just GETTING to that callback

Comment: Does that `GsDevice` have a place where you can stash a value from `GCHandle.ToPointer()` and retrieve it inside the callback function ?  (If it is under your control, stick in a `gcroot<System::Object^>`)

Comment: Or since you have a `DeviceUnmanagedMembers` instance that isn't subject to being moved around garbage collection, stick a `gcroot<Device^>` in there, and stash a copy of `DeviceUnmanagedMembers* m_p` in the `GSDevice` to be retrieved inside the callback.  That will save you messing with `GCHandle` by hand.

Comment: Good idea.  I'm going to try passing a `GCHandle` to the client.   What `GCHandleType` should it be?  `Pinned`?  If that doesn't work I might make an unamanaged "relay" object that lives inside the managed DLL.  I just realized that's a big difference between the callback case the works and the one that doesn't.  In the case that works, I'm passing the callback to something inside my own DLL

Comment: As long as you use `GCHandle::FromIntPtr` to get back your tracking handle, you don't need `GCHandleType.Pinned`.  And get rid of the `std::string` from the callback signature if you possibly can, use `const char*` and length parameters or else `BSTR` (`SysAllocString`).

Comment: @Joe: If the GsDevice didn't give you a way to store an arbitrary pointer, you could still maintain a `std::map<GsDevice*, gcroot<Device^>>` and do the lookup from inside the callback function.  Just having the `GsDevice*` passed to the callback is enough to make everything work.

Comment: Well I'm the author of the GsDevice so I get to make it do whatever I want.  I'll try to give all of these things a try and check, back.  Thank you for all the great advice

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer because while Ben's suggestions were excellent, the cause appears to have been something different:   My liberal use of header-only, unmanaged classes in C++/CLI managed code.  I've slowly come to realize that  C++/CLI assemblies can become confused by this.

I unexpectedly saw my problems fixed merely by moving unmanaged code from header files to their own .CPP files (with attendant  `#pragma unmanaged` statements for good measure).  I was able to leave all my Interop code just as it was.  No gcroots or data-type changes needed.

My best guess is that header-only code causes the compiler to fail to generate all of the necessary unmanaged-to-managed transitions in some places and that without such transitions, callbacks just don't work.

This was all complicated by having the added effect of making the debugger simply ignore breakpoints ***even when the code executed*** -- but only sometimes.   I would repeatedly see a breakpoint on a log statement get hit far fewer times than the statement itself dumped.  Again, all this seems to have been fixed merely by separating .CPP and .H unmanaged code.

Comment: You did put the debugger in Mixed (Managed + Native) mode right?

Comment: Yes.  I'm actually debugging a managed application that uses my unmanaged C++ SDK (with the C++/CLI layer in between).  I pretty much run in mixed mode all the time.  I was hitting the managed and unmanaged breakpoints just fine except in the code path of the callbacks